# Defining a struct in flex error C++

Tags: c++, flex-lexer

I want to define a struct in a flex program :

```
%{

#include <math.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

struct Node{
    string action;
    vector<Node> vecini[];
};

%}
```

and even though I include vector and string I still get this errors: 
error: ‘string’ does not name a type
error: field ‘vecini’ has incomplete type

Thank you !

Comment: This won't work: at the point you're declaring the `vecini` member, `Node` is an incomplete type. You may want to use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>>` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both vector and string are in the `std` namespace so you should add it to the declaration of member variables of those types. Change the code to:

```
%{

#include <math.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

struct Node{
    std::string action;
    std::vector<Node*> vecini[];
};

%}
```

EDIT: (thanks to Kerrek SB): also you can not define a vector of Node as a member of Node. Instead use a vector of pointers to node like so: `std::vector<Node*> vecini[];`

Comment: @KerrekSB true. Thank you. Also defining a vector of the class you are defining as a member in it will never work.

Comment: Great that's the answer so simple :)))

Answer (score 2):

Use fully qualified names for string and vector, for example:

```
std::string action;
^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Note that, string and vector are defined only in the `std` namespace, so you need to specify the fully qualified name to tell the compiler under which namespace to find them.